# Deploy error An unexpected error occurred: "ESOCKETTIMEDOUT". App Service Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, deployment, yarnpkg

I have a big problem trying to deploy a react app to a azure app service with visual studio azure app service extension, im getting this error

```
info There appears to be trouble with your network connection. Retrying...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/date-fns/-/date-fns-2.0.0-alpha.27.tgz: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT".
```

Im using yarn and i read that increase the network timeout maybe solve this. But how i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using yarn and i read that increase the network timeout maybe
> solve this. But how i can do it?

You can try running it in your **terminal** :

```js
$ yarn install --network-timeout 1000000
```

And also try to **clear** the `cache` by running the below cmd

```js
$ yarn cache clean
$ yarn // to install dependencies, no need for "yarn install"
```

Please refer the below links for more information:

.[yarn is having troubles with the network connection | SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52135815/yarn-is-having-troubles-with-the-network-connection/52135833) .

.  [React deployment keeps failing with ESOCKETTIMEDOUT | MS Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/551407/react-deployment-keeps-failing-with-esockettimedou.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to NOT run build on Azure. Do this by answering NO when you publish.
[image]

Have you already made the settings to build on Azure (answered yes) .. undo by deleting the following files

.vscode\settings.json

.deployment

Answer (score 0):

Create the file .yarnrc, and write into file:

> network-timeout 1000000

Save file & deploy your app with the file